# Angular $scope.$watch in object of arrays

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.testObj={};
angular.forEach(results, function (value,index) {
$scope.testObj[index]=value.arr;

console.log($scope.testObj[index]);
console.log(index);
$scope.$watch('testObj',function(newVal, oldVal) {       
        console.log(newVal, oldVal) ;  
      },true
);
})
```

The above code works fine (do not worry about `results`;it is an array). The problem lies when I am trying that:

```
$scope.$watch('testObj[index]',function(newVal, oldVal) {       
            console.log(newVal, oldVal) ;  
          },true
    );
```

I have no idea why that happens and I am getting `undefined` from both **newVal, oldVal**. How may I solve that?

By the way `testObj[0]` works...

Comment: why dont you assign to a object and do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? It is not clear at all

Comment: you are trying to pass w variable `index` to a function arguments, what do you expect bro ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$scope.myvar = testObj[index];
$scope.$watch('myvar',function(newVal, oldVal) {       
            console.log(newVal, oldVal) ;  
          },true
);
```

**EDIT**

If you render change your array in ng-repeat, you can to use ng-change directive and pass in it  $index parameter.

```
<div ng-repeat="arr in myvar">
   <input type="text" ng-model="arr.location" ng-change="changeValue($index)"/>
</div>
```

or use a loop and access using its index

```
$scope.$watch('myvar', function (newValue, oldValue) {
   for(var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {

   }
}, true);
```

Comment: However, I want to keep track of all the arrays: testObj[0], testObj[1] ... The above won't do my job

Comment: I am not using the view for that, only the controller. Is there any way for $scope.$watch to understand the first argument the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

$watchGroup can come to your need more doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 0):

You got the other way round. Because `forEach` only executed once, the `$watchers` inside will only watch it once and then was tore down. What you need to do is watch the collection, then put your `forEach` insde.

```
$scope.$watch('testObj', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  angular.forEach(newVal, function(value, index) {
    $scope.testObj[index] = value.arr;
    console.log($scope.testObj[index]);
    console.log(index);
  })
}, true);
```